# MVC Controller unable to find Api Controller (same project)

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

(Sorry if my english sucks a little)

I'm trying to call an api method from a mvc controller but the mvc seems unable to find the method. I set the route in the mvc controller as

`[Route("[controller]")]`

and in the api controller as

`[Route("api/[controller]")]`

In the startup.cs file i added this command to enable default route

`app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();`

Mvc controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        IEnumerable<Utente> utenti = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57279/");
            var Res = await client.GetAsync("api/utente/GetAll");

            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask = Res.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<Utente>>();
                utenti = readTask.Result;
            }
            else
            {
                utenti = Enumerable.Empty<Utente>();

                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error. Please contact administrator.");
            }
        }
        return View(utenti);
    }
```

Api code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAll()
    {
        IList<Utente> utenti = null;

        using (_utenteContext)
        {
            utenti = _utenteContext.Utenti.Select(u => new Utente()
                        {
                            id = u.id,
                            user = u.user,
                            password = u.password
                        }).ToList<Utente>();
        }

        if (utenti.Count == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(utenti);
    }
```

The problem might be that I'm following an old example for both mvc and api controllers in same project, but I'd like if you guys could help me with it.

In the:

`var Res = await client.GetAsync("api/utente/GetAll");`

I always get {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found',...} no matter the changes I make to the code.

**EDIT:**

Whole Api Controller (I was trying also with a POST method but it doesn't work either)

```
using AdrianWebApi.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace AdrianWebApi.Controllers.api
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UtenteController : ApiController
{
    private readonly UtenteContext _utenteContext;

    public UtenteController(UtenteContext context)
    {
        _utenteContext = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAll()
    {
        IList<Utente> utenti = null;

        using (_utenteContext)
        {
            utenti = _utenteContext.Utenti.Select(u => new Utente()
                        {
                            id = u.id,
                            user = u.user,
                            password = u.password
                        }).ToList<Utente>();
        }

        if (utenti.Count == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(utenti);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult PostNewUtente(Utente utente)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest("Not a valid model");

        using (_utenteContext)
        {
            _utenteContext.Utenti.Add(new Utente()
            {
                id = utente.id,
                user = utente.user,
                password = utente.password
            });

            _utenteContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT 2**
Startup class if it's useful:

```
using AdrianWebApi.Models;
using AdrianWebApi.Models.DataManager;
using AdrianWebApi.Models.Repository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace AdrianWebApi
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<UtenteContext>(options =>{options.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=dbutenti;User ID=root;password=root;");});
        services.AddScoped<IDataRepository<Utente>, DataManager>();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT 3** Post method MVC if someone is interested, working, at least for me:

```
[Route("Add")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add([FromForm]Utente utente)
    {
        if (utente.password == null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57279/api/");

                //HTTP POST
                var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<Utente>("utente", utente);
                postTask.Wait();

                var result = postTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("GetAll");
                }
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server Error. Please contact administrator.");
            return View(utente);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show more of the controller in the API? Also, is this MVC5 rather then ASP.NET MVC Core?

Comment: It's MVC5, I'm editing to post the whole api controller.

Comment: Could you be missing `app.UseWebApi()`?

Comment: When I try to add it in startup.cs it tells me that IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseWebApi' and no accessible extension method 'UseWebApi' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found.



Do I have to install Owin Nuget?

Comment: does the api work from a browser? There may be some configuration needed for cross-controller calls

Comment: Nope, I get 404 error when calling the api

Comment: Are you sure the controller is not being found? Since your action method returns a `NotFound`, that could also be the problem.

Comment: Well, I tried commenting the if that return a NotFound and I stil get the 404 Not Found thing. Should I post other classes so you could check? I'm stuck on this for 2hours already...

Comment: Could you try "api/utente" instead of "api/utente/getall" ?

Comment: Tried like this var Res = await client.GetAsync("api/utente"); , still not found.

Comment: Added the startup.cs if it might be useful for solving the problem

Comment: This is confusing now. You said it was MVC5 but you've just posted ASP.NET Core code.

Comment: Sorry if I mislead you, I actually had to search what's the differences between the twos because I'm new to web api development and the template I used when creating the project resembled the one for MVC5. Sorry again

Comment: Does your api call work under Postman?

Comment: No, it returns blank

Comment: But your controller is using MVC5 and your startup shows .NET Core. You can't mix them like that.

Comment: What's the best (and simplest) solution? Change code in Startup to match MVC5 or use .NET Core in controller? In fact I should stick with MVC5, so if you could help me edit the startup I would be very happy.

Comment: You can't just "edit" the code to make it into MVC5, there's an entire project system behind it that would need retrofitting. The solution is to make a proper ASP.NET MVC Core controller.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I solved the problem using Pieter answer. Thanks again you all.

Comment: If you are using MVC5, and OWIN is not installed, where does the startup.cs come from?

Comment: I was using .NET Core and I fucked up the project a little bit, now it's all working, thanks for your concern :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try commenting out your controller and replacing it with this code below, then go to `api/utente/` and see if you get a result. If you do then replace what you need with your code.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace AdrianWebApi.Controllers.api
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "Test 1", " Test 2" };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you now the mvc controller is getting the data from the api :)

Comment: If anyone needs it I managed to fix also the post method adding an if that check if the password is null before calling the mvc method like this: if (utente.password == null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            { // all code from add